# Relation Global Object and the Object object

Tags: javascript, object

I was trying to understand what the relationship is between the global object in javascript and all the other built-in object.
As I understand everything in javascript is in the Object object, also the global object. At least it seems that way when I'm using these commands:

`console.log(globalThis.__proto__.constructor) // Window() console.log(globalThis.__proto__.__proto__.constructor) // WindowProperties() console.log(globalThis.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.constructor) // EventTarget console.log(globalThis.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.constructor) // Object`

Is this correct?

Comment: Most things in JS is an object. Window is the global object. Window is not the same as Object.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking. `globalThis.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.constructor === Object // true` and `globalThis === Object // false`  so they're not the same.

Comment: Also have a read of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63819025/javascript-prototypes-and-inheritance

Comment: The question is if the global object is a part of the object object.

Comment: The global object is an instance of “Object”. In JS terms Object is the end prototype of the global object.

Comment: Thanks, that was also what I imagined.