# javascript prototypes and inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

My question is Object is last on prototype chain all objects inherit properties and methods from it how it is inherit methods from Function.prototype, why `Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype` // true, why `Object.__proto__` is not null.

Comment: No normal object inherits from `Object` in javascript. They all inherit from `Object.prototype` (which is also the `Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype)`). You will find that `Obect.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) === null` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental `Object` in JavaScript has to have a way for it to be instantiated, so it requires a `prototype` object to aid in lines like this:

```
let myObj = new Object();
```

And that is why `Object.__proto__` is not `null`.

The [`Function` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#:%7E:text=Values%20can%20be%20passed%20to,brief%2C%20they%20are%20Function%20objects.) is a special type of object that facilitates object instantiation via a constructor and when used this way is known as a "constructor function". So, it makes sense for `Object` to inherit from a `Function` object so that object instances can be made.

Comment: its mean that Function and Object inherit methods and properties from each other ?

Comment: why Function is not last on prototype chain ?

Comment: @javascriptlover `Function` is the last of the prototype chain. As you correctly point out `Object._proto__ === Function()`

Comment: mdn says Object is last on prototype chain.

Comment: I think you are confusing `__proto__` and `prototype`. `__proto__` is the actual object that is used in the lookup chain to resolve methods, etc. `prototype` is the object that is used to build `__proto__` when you create an object with new

Comment: @ScottMarcus What do you mean by "*The Function object is a special type of object that facilitates object instantiation via a constructor*"?

Comment: I don't know if this helps or not, but `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object))` is `null`. `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)` is a function, but not `Function`.

Comment: Why Function.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true

Answer (score 0):

Function is also an object. So it inherits from Object too.

But don't be confused by `Object.__proto__`. That's something the browser adds and isn't actually part of the language. So don't rely on it or use it.

Essentially, `Function.prototype` is `Object.__proto__`.

Comment: why Function is not last on prototype chain ?

Comment: Because Function inherits from Object.

Comment: No, `Object` inherits from `Function`, which is implemented as native code. This is how/why objects have the ability to be called with the `new` keyword as constructor functions. Open your browser console and type: `Function.prototype;` and see what you get.

Comment: @ScottMarcus What Geuis meant is that Function is a subclass of Object, and all functions are objects. No, `Object` does not inherit from `Function`. At best, it does inherit from `Function.prototype`, and it's an `instanceof Function`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus riiight. Bit rusty, I've been off work for a few months. Sorry. Yeah, Object does inherit from Function, which is why you can do `new Function()` and `new Object()`. But @Bergi is clarifying what I was trying to say originally.